# Debian 8 iptables firewall issue

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall

I have weird problem with my firewall. I can't ping my server from my pc and ping anything from server. It is weird because I use only iptables and I use on it this rules:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

So I think there are no denying rules, and accept all connections. I can't ping server, I get request time out and 100% loss, there ale no other firewall rules.

My ISP is ovh, I get emails from automatic server reporter that they can't ping my server too and says that is my firewall software issue, but I don't understand why is it doing that when all rules are deleted...

Comment: And what does `iptables -L -vn` show?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can begin by remove your current firewall and check if you have other error.

Next you try to create a new firewall with basic rules.

**Don't forget to start by SSH rules for don't locked your server.**

You can check this post for an example of basic rules:

[Iptables Essentials: Common Firewall Rules and Commands](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands#service-ssh)